# I don't know the difference between the forEach and the for

Tags: for-loop, foreach

```
function solution(s) {
  const str = s.split(" ");
  return str
    .map((ele) => {
      let result = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          result += ele[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
          result += ele[i].toLowerCase();
        }
      }
      return result;
    })
    .join(" ");

// console.log(solution("try hello world"));
```

In this way, I can get a correct answer which is TrY HeLlO WoRlD.
However,

```
function solution(s) {
  const str = s.split(" ");
  return str.map((ele) => {
    let result = "";
    ele.split("").forEach((value, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        result += value.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        result += value.toLowerCase();
      }
    });
    return result;
  });
  .join(" ");
}
```

In this way, I can't get a answer.
How should I correct the answer which is using forEach?
Correct answer is TrY HeLlO WoRlD.

**

I'm not good at writing English.
I ask for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your only issue was the semicolon that did not let you chain the .join.

```
function solution(s) {
  const str = s.split(" ");
  return str.map((ele) => {
    let result = "";
    ele.split("").forEach((value, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        result += value.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        result += value.toLowerCase();
      }
    });
    return result;
  }).join(" ");  // no semicolon so you can chain the join
};
```